# Better way to write if condition in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if args.size == 5
  value_for,alt_currency_id,amount,exchange_rate_code,tran_dt = args
else
  value_for,alt_currency_id,amount,exchange_rate_code,year_no,period_no = args
end
```

Any Better way to write this condition ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely is a code smell, specially since the variable is called `args`. If you're passing all these arguments as optional values, the best approach is make the variable arguments into a hash.

```
def whatever(value_for, alt_currency_id, amount, options = {})
  tran_dt = options[:tran_dt]
  year_no = options[:year_no]
  period_no = options[:period_no]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just skip the condition entirely.  If you don't have the fifth argument, `period_no` will simply be `nil`.

If period_no needed to be set to some default you could follow up with:

```
period_no ||= sane_default
```

Comment: If i have five args than trans_dt value will be a date like 20100913. And i have more than five args than year_no will be a year like 2010. How it possible with your answer..

Answer (score 2):

To strictly meet your requirements, I'd do this:

```
value_for, alt_currency_id, amount, exchange_rate_code = args.shift(4)
tran_dt, year_no, period_no = [nil, nil, nil] # or some sensible defaults
case args.size
when 1 then tran_dt = args.shift
when 2 then year_no, period_no = args.shift(2)
end
```

But this code has a smell to it.  I'd look at redesigning how that method gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps assign `period_no` to `nil` by default, and use that to determine which argument set you are working with:

```
def process_record(value_for, alt_currency_id, amount, exchange_rate_code, tran_dt, period_no=nil)
  year_no = period_no ? tran_dt : nil
  puts "tran_dt: #{tran_dt.inspect}"
  puts "year_no: #{year_no.inspect}"
  puts "period_no: #{period_no.inspect}"
end

process_record(:foo, :bar, :baz, :buz, Time.now)
# Output:
#
# tran_dt: Mon Sep 13 15:52:54 -0400 2010
# year_no: nil
# period_no: nil

process_record(:foo, :bar, :baz, :buz, 2010, 1)
# Output:
#
# tran_dt: 2010
# year_no: 2010
# period_no: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of [DRYing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up your code a bit:

```
value_for, alt_currency_id, amount, exchange_rate_code, year_no, period_no = args
if period_no.nil?
  tran_dt = year_no
  year_no = nil # May or may not be needed, depending on later code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has two ternary operators as well that I'm aware of

```
a = true  ? 'a' : 'b' #=> "a"  
b = false ? 'a' : 'b' #=> "b"
```

or

```
a = (true  && 'a') || b #=> "a"  
b = (false && 'a') || b #=> "b"
```

Comment: The second one isn't a ternary operator. It's two binary operators, chained. Not that it's super relevant to the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Are you processing commandline? Just leave as it is, for me it is most readable at first look :) Otherwise it may smell perlish.
You simply see what is required set for 5 arguments or else.
If these are not command line args I suggest introducing hash.